# unable to boot from live USB

Tags: grub2, boot-failure, live-usb

*Edit: Welp, I re-made the live USB and now it works fine. Thanks for the replies! Another computing lesson learned the hard way.*

I was messing around with my new dual-boot (win7 and the latest ubuntu, 12.04 I think?), and I deleted some partitions that I shouldn't have.

When I boot up the machine, I get:

```
error: no such partition.
grub rescue> _
```

I know that I could probably fix this by booting from the live USB. But I can't boot from the live USB either! On startup, I can get "boot from drive" options by pressing F12. (This is how I installed Ubuntu in the first place.) But when I select the USB drive, I get this error:

```
error: no such device: [long string of letters and numbers].
grub rescue> _
```

I've searched around for a fix but most threads addressing the first problem suggest booting from live drive. And I can't do that!

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: You might need to get access to another computer and remake the Live USB. Be careful with deleting partition next time.

Comment: Is booting from CD an option?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a problem where you messed up your Grub. Or, at least, this is the same thing I got when I messed up my grub. Specifically, when I attempted to install BURG. That's my experience with the first part of your problem with the "error: no such partition".

The second part of your problem, happened, I don't know when/why, to me as well. If I remember correctly, booting from Flash Drive did not work for me either, but booting from CD Image did. I would try that. Either way, I got through both of the problems. For the second part of your problem, I reinstalled Ubuntu completely and that fixed everything, but I feel as though you might just be able to reinstall Grub or something to fix both of your problems.